# How to find element iTunes Connect website for scrapy(crawling)?

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, web-crawler

I need CFBundleversion of my apps so i've tried scrapy iTunes Connect website but i can't get element.

I tried:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/login")

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='account_name_text_field']")
```

I am receiving the following error:

> elenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to
>   locate element: //input[@id='account_name_text_field']

i think the site is different structure...
what should i do?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //input[@id='account_name_text_field']

Comment: @ItamarMushkin result of driver.page_source is different from browser view source
i don't know why different results

Comment: Please edit these into the question body, not just in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with you locator :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='account_name_text_field']")
```

It inside `iframe`, you need switch first, use `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it` and `visibility_of_element_located`, like this:

```
driver.get('https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/login')

WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(expected_conditions.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "aid-auth-widget-iFrame")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='account_name_text_field']")))
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='account_name_text_field']")
elem.send_keys("userName")
```

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
```